# Reading binary files generated on a linux machine on a windows machine

Tags: c, windows, linux, binary

I am trying to read binary files generated on a Linux machine (OpenSuse 11.2, 64bit) on a Windows (xp 32bit) machine using the same c code, just compiled on the respective machines.  On the windows machine I am using MinGW compiler.

I can read and write the files without error on the Linux machine however, when I try to read the files on a windows machine, the code seems to be failing on an end of file error.

specifically: `feof(file)==16`

Does anybody know what the problem might be? The bigger problem might be that fact that my C skills are not very strong...

I pulled some of the write code out (Well at least I think). Note: there is an option to write out ASCII files, however I prefer not to:

```
void write_node_data(void *nndes, void *x, void *y, void *z)
 {
   int tmpnndes;
   float *tempx, *tempy, *tempz;
   double *tempx64, *tempy64, *tempz64;
   long tmpnndes64, longcount, totnodes;

   strcpy(tmpname, "nodes   ");  

   if (iflag64)
      totnodes = tmpnndes64 = *((long *) nndes);
   else
      totnodes = tmpnndes = *((int *) nndes);

   if (rflag64)
     {
      tempx64 = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * totnodes);
      tempy64 = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * totnodes);
      tempz64 = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * totnodes);
     }
   else
     {
      tempx = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float) * totnodes);
      tempy = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float) * totnodes);
      tempz = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float) * totnodes);
     }
    if (rflag64)
      {
       for (longcount = 0; longcount < totnodes; longcount++)
     {
      tempx64[longcount] = *((double *) x + longcount);
          tempy64[longcount] = *((double *) y + longcount);
      tempz64[longcount] = *((double *) z + longcount);
         }
      }
    else
      {
       for (longcount = 0; longcount < totnodes; longcount++)
         {
          tempx[longcount] = *((float *) x + longcount); 
          tempy[longcount] = *((float *) y + longcount); 
          tempz[longcount] = *((float *) z + longcount);
     }
      }

   if (filetype == IEEE_F)
      fwrite(tmpname,sizeof(char),8,fp);
   else
      fprintf(fp,"nodes  "); 

   if (iflag64)
     {
      if (filetype == IEEE_F)
         fwrite(&tmpnndes64, INT64, 1, fp);
      else
         fprintf(fp,"%ld\n",tmpnndes64);
      n_nodes = tmpnndes64;
     }
   else
     {
      if (filetype == IEEE_F)
         fwrite(&tmpnndes, INT32, 1, fp);
      else
         fprintf(fp,"%d\n",tmpnndes);
      n_nodes = tmpnndes;
     }
   if (rflag64)
     {
      if (filetype == IEEE_F)
        {
         fwrite(tempx64, FLOAT64, n_nodes, fp);
         fwrite(tempy64, FLOAT64, n_nodes, fp);
         fwrite(tempz64, FLOAT64, n_nodes, fp);
        }
      else
        {
         write_ascii_double(n_nodes, tempx64);
         write_ascii_double(n_nodes, tempy64);
         write_ascii_double(n_nodes, tempz64);
        }
      free(tempx64), free(tempy64), free(tempz64);
     }
   else
     {
      if (filetype == IEEE_F)
        {
         fwrite(tempx, FLOAT32, n_nodes, fp);
         fwrite(tempy, FLOAT32, n_nodes, fp);
         fwrite(tempz, FLOAT32, n_nodes, fp);
        }
      else
        {
         write_ascii_float(n_nodes, tempx);
         write_ascii_float(n_nodes, tempy);
         write_ascii_float(n_nodes, tempz);
        }
      free(tempx), free(tempy), free(tempz);
     }
 }
```

And the reading code:

```
if (lstructuredflag == 0 || lstructuredflag == 2)
     {
      lxic = (double *)malloc((lnodes)*sizeof(double));
      lyic = (double *)malloc((lnodes)*sizeof(double));
      lzic = (double *)malloc((lnodes)*sizeof(double));
      if (lxic == NULL || lyic == NULL || lzic == NULL)
        {
         gmvrdmemerr();
         return;
        }
      if (ftype != ASCII)
        {
         if (ftype == IEEEI4R8 || ftype == IEEEI8R8)
           {
            tmpdouble = (double *)malloc((3*lnodes)*sizeof(double));
            if (tmpdouble == NULL)
              {
               gmvrdmemerr();
               return;
              }
            binread(tmpdouble,doublesize,DOUBLE,3*lnodes,gmvin);
            ioerrtst(gmvin);
            if (node_inp_type == 0)  /*  nodes type  */
              {
               for (i = 0; i < lnodes; i++)
                 {
                  lxic[i] = tmpdouble[i];
                  lyic[i] = tmpdouble[lnodes+i];
                  lzic[i] = tmpdouble[2*lnodes+i];
                 }
              }
            if (node_inp_type == 1)  /*  nodev type  */
              {
               for (i = 0; i < lnodes; i++)
                 {
                  lxic[i] = tmpdouble[3*i];
                  lyic[i] = tmpdouble[3*i+1];
                  lzic[i] = tmpdouble[3*i+2];
                 }
              }
            FREE(tmpdouble);
           }
         else
           {
            tmpfloat = (float *)malloc((3*lnodes)*sizeof(float));
            if (tmpfloat == NULL)
              {
               gmvrdmemerr();
               return;
              }
            binread(tmpfloat,floatsize,FLOAT,3*lnodes,gmvin);
            ioerrtst(gmvin);
            if (node_inp_type == 0)  /*  nodes type  */
              {
               for (i = 0; i < lnodes; i++)
                 {
                  lxic[i] = tmpfloat[i];
                  lyic[i] = tmpfloat[lnodes+i];
                  lzic[i] = tmpfloat[2*lnodes+i];
                 }
              }
            if (node_inp_type == 1)  /*  nodev type  */
              {
               for (i = 0; i < lnodes; i++)
                 {
                  lxic[i] = tmpfloat[3*i];
                  lyic[i] = tmpfloat[3*i+1];
                  lzic[i] = tmpfloat[3*i+2];
                 }
              }
            FREE(tmpfloat);
           }
        }
      if (ftype == ASCII)
        {
         tmpdouble = (double *)malloc((3*lnodes)*sizeof(double));
         if (tmpdouble == NULL)
              {
               gmvrdmemerr();
               return;
              }
         rdfloats(tmpdouble,3*lnodes,gmvin);
         if (node_inp_type == 0)  /*  nodes type  */
           {
            for (i = 0; i < lnodes; i++)
              {
               lxic[i] = tmpdouble[i];
               lyic[i] = tmpdouble[lnodes+i];
               lzic[i] = tmpdouble[2*lnodes+i];
              }
           }
         if (node_inp_type == 1)  /*  nodev type  */
           {
            for (i = 0; i < lnodes; i++)
              {
               lxic[i] = tmpdouble[3*i];
               lyic[i] = tmpdouble[3*i+1];
               lzic[i] = tmpdouble[3*i+2];
              }
           }
         FREE(tmpdouble);
        }
     }
```

the function Binread:

```
int binread(void* ptr, int size, int type, long nitems, FILE* stream)
{
  int ret_stat;

#ifdef CRAY

  float *floatptr, *floatbuf; 
  double *doubleptr, *doublebuf; 
  int tierr, ttype, tbitoff;
  char *charptr;
  int  *intptr, *intbuf;
  short *shortptr, *shortbuf;

   tbitoff = 0;  tierr = 0;
   ret_stat = 0;

   switch(type)
     {

      case CHAR:
        charptr = (char *)ptr;
        ret_stat = fread(charptr, size, nitems, stream);
        break;

      case SHORT:
        ttype = 7;
        shortbuf = (short *)malloc(size*nitems);
        shortptr = (short *)ptr;

        ret_stat = fread(shortbuf, size, nitems, stream);
        tierr = IEG2CRAY(&ttype, &nitems, shortbuf, &tbitoff, shortptr);
        free(shortbuf);
        break;

      case INT:
        ttype = 1;
        intptr = (int *)ptr;
        intbuf = (int *)malloc(size*nitems);

        ret_stat = fread(intbuf, size, nitems, stream);
        tierr = IEG2CRAY(&ttype, &nitems, intbuf, &tbitoff, intptr);
        free(intbuf);
        break;

      case FLOAT:
        ttype = 2;
        floatptr = (float *)ptr;
        floatbuf = (float *)malloc(size*nitems);

        ret_stat = fread(floatbuf, size, nitems, stream);
        tierr = IEG2CRAY(&ttype, &nitems, floatbuf, &tbitoff, floatptr);
        free(floatbuf);
        break;

      case DOUBLE:
        ttype = 3;
        doubleptr = (double *)ptr;
        doublebuf = (double *)malloc(size*nitems);

        ret_stat = fread(doublebuf, size, nitems, stream);
        tierr = IEG2CRAY(&ttype, &nitems, doublebuf, &tbitoff, doubleptr);
        free(doublebuf);
        break;

      case WORD:
        intptr = (int *)ptr;
        ret_stat = fread(intptr, size, nitems, stream);
        break;

      default:
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: Cannot match input datatype.\n");
        gmv_data.keyword = GMVERROR;
        return;
     }

     if(tierr != 0)
       {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: Cannot convert IEEE data to CRAY\n");
        gmv_data.keyword = GMVERROR;
        return;
       }

     return ret_stat;

#else

   ret_stat = fread(ptr, size, nitems, stream);

   if (swapbytes_on && type != CHAR && type != WORD)
      swapbytes(ptr, size, nitems);

   return ret_stat;

#endif

}
```

Disclaimer: I did not write this code I am simply trying to use it.

Comment: Are they the same machine? If not, you have to consider endianness, word size, etc., which means that you need to choose an endianess and word size for your code. What's the file writing code?

Comment: What you need to post is `binread`

Comment: You might want to learn about binary serialization (e.g. XDR or ASN1) or use a textual format (JSON, YAML, XML??). See e.g. http://s11n.net/s11n/ & http://json.org/

Comment: I would love to do that however this code is used in an application that I don't have all the source code for. If it was up to me I would write it out in the HDF5 standard since it is rather large simulation data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you specify "b" to open the file in binary mode? Try using `fopen(fname, "rb")`

Comment: This might have fixed it. I am no longer receiving the feof error. I need to check the data now to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to directly load e.g. structures, don't. Once you switch compilers, there's absolutely no reason to believe the structure is byte-for-byte identical to what you had on the other machine. Padding and alignment might differ, even on the same CPU.

What I mean is don't do this:

```
struct foo my_foo;

fwrite(&my_foo, sizeof my_foo, 1, my_binary_file);
```

Instead, serialize and de-serialize each field of the struct(s) separately.

Comment: I'm not sure that parsing & alignment depend on the compiler; it technically depends on the ABI conventions followed by the compiler. For instance, many Linux C compilers follow the same ABI conventions (otherwise they won't be able to call standard functions of `libc`)

Answer (score 0):

I may be barking up the wrong tree here, but I think

```
feof(file)=16
```

used as a part of an "if" will generate an error because it is being used/interpreted as an *assignment* to a function by virtue of the *single* equals operator. It should likely read:

```
if (feof(file)==16) /* setting aside the comparison to 16 rather than for 0 or non-zero */
```

Comment: No problem :)  You might need to post a bit more of that code for us to get a better idea of where the problem might be, then.

Comment: feof(file)==16 doesn't make sense either. feof() returns a non-zero value when it finds the end of the file. The standard makes no guarantees of what that value is, it could be any random non-zero number. Correct use of that function is `if(feof(file))`.